# Unable to connect to Azure Servicebus through Python 3.x

Tags: python, servicebus

I am trying to connect to the Servicebus through Python, so I followed [these steps](https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/).

After that, I tried to connect to an existing Queue or Topic using the code below. However, it throws an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you share your code and the **exact** error message?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to have forgotten to paste your code into your question! In addition, you should copy and paste the error message you're getting into your question so that others know how to help you more effectively!

Comment: Please share the error here. also, check out the latest servicebus version https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/